# Edit json using Perl

Tags: perl

I need to edit the below config file using Perl. I need to check if `cp` is 10000 and set `custcap` to 99999 if so.

If the `cp` is not equal to 10000, just exit out of the file without making changes.

My understanding is we can use Perl file handles to open the file, and the JSON module for editing, but I'm not really sure about editing the file.

Can some one help me out with editing the file?

```
{
    "version": "15320029",
    "global": {
        "ap": {
            "log": "info",
            "hyd": {
                "log": "info",
                "qo": false
            }
        },
        "cus": [
            {
                **"cp": "10000"**,
                "ser": "XYZ",
                "usesr": false,
                "services": {
                    "acc": {
                        "ips": {
                            "usesr": false
                        }
                    }
                },
                "q": {
                    "policy": "CAP",
                    **"custcap": 3000000**
                }
            },
            {
            "cp": "10441",
                "ser": "abc",
                "usesr": false,
                "services": {
                    "acc": {
                        "ips": {
                            "usesr": false
                        }
                    }
                },
                "q": {
                    "policy": "CAP",
                    "custcap": 3000000
                }
            }
         ]  
      }
```

Code snippet :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

open my $fh, "<", "data.json";
my $json = <$fh>;
close $fh;


my $data = decode_json($json);

$data->{'q'}->{'custcap'}->[1] = "9999";

open my $fh, ">", "data.json";

print $fh encode_json($data);

close $fh;
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem #1: You just read the first line of the file.

One trick to read the whole file at once is to use `local $/`. With some error checking and scoping, that will look like:

```
my $qfn = 'data.json';

my $json;
{
   open(my $fh, "<", $qfn)
      or die("Can't open file \"$qfn\": $!\n");
   local $/;
   $json = <$fh>;
}
```

---

Problem #2: You need some kind of loop since you need to check each of the objects in `cus`.

```
for my $cus (@{ $data->{global}{cus} }) {
   $cus->{q}{custcap} = 99999
      if $cus->{cp} == 10000;
}
```

Comment: But , I just noticed that "versio‌​n":"15320029" which was the first line of the file  is now getting printed at the end.

Comment: The format of the file looks good .but the order of the parameters and the curly braces are completely messed up

Comment: Yup, but that's fine. From the JSON spec: "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs." ("Object" is the name of the `{ }` construct.)

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that the order of the parameters in the file doesn't change. If the format changes , this file will not get pushed to our test machines. A syntax check is performed by a process , and if the config files doesn't conform to the format , config push will be rejected. So is there a way to ensure that the order of the parameters remain intact.

Comment: The format didn't change. The order is meaningless. And no, not as long as you use hashes, and the JSON module uses hashes.

Comment: In this case order is important. If the order changes the config push will fail.

Comment: Either the order is meaningless and your push tool is buggy, or the order is meaningful and you shouldn't be using JSON, because in JSON, the order of object attributes is meaningless.

Comment: One last question. If i were to change the version number in the config file how do i do that. Version is not part of cust [ ] . I'm curious to know how we change it ?

Comment: Look at the data dumper output. It's in the hash referenced by `$data`.

Answer (score 1):

@kjpires is correct that the posted snippet does not load the entire file, and will not parses it correctly.

That's only half the solution. The posted snippet traverses the JSON structure incorrectly.

The root node has a `global` node which has a `cus` node that is an array, and each `cus` node can have a `q` node which has a `custcap` property. Your snippet omits the `cus` array and attempts to access `q` directly

Your requirements aren't specific as to what to do if `custcap` appears multiple times. Assuming that you need to update each occurrence of `custcap` if its current value is 10000 with 99999 then you need to replace

`$data->{'q'}->{'custcap'}->[1] = "9999";`

with something like this:

```
for my $customer (@{$data->{global}{cus}}) {
      $customer->{q}{custcap} = 99999 if ($customer->{cp} == 10000);
}
```

Comment: When i compile the code i see the following error : or } expected while parsing object/hash, at character offset 1106 (before "\n")

Comment: I think this has to do with your JSON object. It's missing a closing }

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use JSON;


    my $json;
    {
    open my $fh, "<", "cfg.txt"
    or die("Can't open file \"file name\": $!\n");
    local $/;
    $json = <$fh>;
    }

    my $data = decode_json($json);


    for my $cus (@{ $data->{global}{cus} }) {
    $cus->{q}{custcap} = 99999
    if $cus->{cp} == 10000;
    }

    #open the file and save the changes
   {
   open my $fh, ">", "file name"
   or die("Can't open file \"file name\": $!\n");
   local $/;
   $json = <$fh>;
   }
~
~

Comment: Sorry for not formatting the code. I'm unable to format it.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that `my $json = <$fh>;` doesn't read the whole file: you are just getting one line of the file (and then parsing just that one line which should probably fail unless it is all on one line).

One quick solution is to undefine the input end-of-line terminator using: `$/ = undef;` before you read your file.  Another solution is to use the [File::Slurp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp) module.